# Scala add contents of two lists

Tags: scala

For the first assignment for the course https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun
I would like to do the following

```
   val l1 = List(1,2,3)
   val l2 = List(4,5,6)

   val lSum = l1.someOperation(l2)
   RES: lSum=List(5,7,9)
```

I could implement someOperation with a loop, but that does not look very scalarish, I am wondering if there is a built in function to achieve this.

Comment: You could do it recursively, it'd be simple AND scala-ish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may zip them and perform addition as usually in map:

```
l1.zip(l2).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `zip`, the standard library also supplies `zipped` which avoids the need to deconstruct any tuples:

`(l1, l2).zipped.map(_ + _)`

Comment: This should arguably be the correct answer, since the use of zipped avoids the creation of an intermediate List of tuples.  More info at #11 on this page: http://tinyurl.com/scala-snippets

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more Scalaish than @om-nom-nom's code. Although Scala is, as languages go, still pretty young, so there is actually still debate about what actually *is* and *isn't* Scalaish:

```
l1 zip l2 map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```